# having my <article> in the center winged by <aside> to the left and right

Tags: css, html

I am trying to have my article box in the center between my left and right aside.

```
      <center>
     <article>        
     </article>
     </center>
```

is not working.

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
```

is not working.

although manually adjusting the margin works or using position relative, but
I want to know  WHY neither `<center>` nor `margin: auto;` are working.

**I am more interested in the WHY more than the how.**

```css
#wrapper{
    width: 900px;
 height: 800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
    font-family: khand,sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold; 
}
#socialmedia1 {
    background-image: url(tw.png);  
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin:38px 10px 0px 0px;

}
#socialmedia2 {
    background-image: url(fb.png);  
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin: 38px 10px 0px 0px;
}
#socialmedia3 {
    background-image: url(insta.png);  
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
    margin: 30px 10px 0px 0px;

}  
 header{
    width: 800px;
 height: 70px;
 border: 3px solid black;
 bottom: 20px;
 position: relative;    /* Had to move this to the bottom
                            to make space for icons*/
 bottom: -40px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
  
 }
 hr{
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 2px;

 }
 .logo{
 background-image :url(logo.png);
 background-size: 140px 140px;
 width: 140px;
 height:140px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 35px;
 left: 20px;
 }
ul{ 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 20px;
}
li a {
 display: block;
 color: black;
 padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #911111;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
article {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
aside{
 width: 120px;       /*logo overlaps gotta use position relative..EDIT Nevermind i could*
 just add margin to make space without fucking erthing up*/
 height: 150px;
 border: 3px solid black; 
    margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
aside.right{
    width: 120px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float: right;
    clear:right;

}
.titlebannerbox{
 width: 120px;
 height: 25px;
 background-color: #911111;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 17px;
    color: white;

 }
.asidelogo{
   width: 27px;
   height: 27px;
   background-size: 27px 27px;
   background-image: url(titlebannerlogo.png);
   position: relative;
   bottom: 60px;
   margin-bottom: -65px; 
}
footer {
 width: 800px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 3px solid black;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
 margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="style.css">
<style>
</style>
</head>
  <body> 
     <div id="wrapper">
       <header> 
           <a href="https://twitter.com" id="socialmedia1"></a>
           <a href="https://facebook.com" id="socialmedia2"></a>
           <a href="https://youtube.com" id="socialmedia3"></a>       
         <div class="logo"></div>    
       </header>
        <nav> 
         <ul>
           <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
         </ul> 
       </nav>

     <aside class="right">
           <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Salary</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$109k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Object C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$108k</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$100k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$94k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$93k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$91k</td>
             </tr>
               <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$90k</td>
             </tr>
           </table>          
       </aside>
       <aside>
         <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Learned</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">HTML</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">60%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>CSS</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">60%</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">0.001%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">0%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>PhP</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">0%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">0%</td>
             </tr>
           </table>
          <center>
         <article>        
         </article>
         </center>
     </aside>
       <aside class="right">
           <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Salary</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$109k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Object C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$108k</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$100k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$94k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$93k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$91k</td>
             </tr>
               <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$90k</td>
             </tr>
           </table>          
       </aside>
       <aside style="color:black">  
         <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Popularity</p>   
         <p class="asidelogo"></p>
         <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">31.2%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">19.6%</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">9.8%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C#</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">7.4%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">7.1%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">6.5%</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">6.1%</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
       </aside>
       <aside class="right">
           <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Salary</p>
           <p class="asidelogo"></p>
           <hr>
           <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 10%">Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$109k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Object C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$108k</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$100k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$94k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">$93k</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$91k</td>
             </tr>
               <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">$90k</td>
             </tr>
           </table>          
       </aside>
       <aside>
         <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Difficulty</p>
         <p class="asidelogo"></p>
         <hr>
         <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;">
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td style="width: 30%;">C</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;vertical-align: sub;">*****</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C+++</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">*****</td>
             </tr> 
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Java</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">****</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>C#</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">***</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Javascript</td>
               <td style="text-align: right">**</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Python</td>
               <td style="text-align:right;">*</td>
             </tr>
             <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
               <td>Ruby</td>
               <td style="text-align: right;">*</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
       </aside>
       <footer>
           <center>
              <img src="logo.png" width="70px" height="70px" vertical-align="bottom"/>
           </center>
       </footer>
     </div> <!-- End of Wrapper-->
       
        


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<center>` is obsolete and should no longer be used. Use CSS instead.

Comment: but I want to know WHY neither <center> nor margin: auto; are working. ***

Comment: What about  margin-left-right:auto?

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..it would be really helpful for us..

Comment: article {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

Comment: You have a `200px` wide `<article>` inside a `120px` wide `<aside>`.

Comment: I don't understand? there is not space in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/00hrh5pv/1/show/)

The reason why the `<article>` was not getting centered was because the `<article>` was inside an `<aside>` and the width of the `<aside>` was much less than the width of the `<article>`. Since, it was inside the `<aside>` it was not getting centered with respect to the screen.

What I have done is that, I added  new class `left` for one of the `aside` which makes it floated to the left. Then, moved the `article` to outside of the `aside`.

The CSS for `left` is as follows

```
aside.left{
    width: 120px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    float: left;
    clear:left;

}
```

and the HTML would be like

```
       <aside class="left">       <-----------see this (added new class ) 
           <p class="titlebannerbox" align="right">Learned</p>
       <p class="asidelogo"></p>
       <hr>
       <table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:-5px;">
         <tbody><tr style="line-height: 15px;">
           <td style="width: 10%">HTML</td>
           <td style="text-align: right">60%</td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
           <td>CSS</td>
           <td style="text-align: right">60%</td>
         </tr> 
         <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
           <td>Javascript</td>
           <td style="text-align: right">0.001%</td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
           <td>Java</td>
           <td style="text-align: right">0%</td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
           <td>PhP</td>
           <td style="text-align: right">0%</td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="line-height: 15px;">
           <td>Ruby</td>
           <td style="text-align: right;">0%</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody></table>

       </aside>
       <article>     <-----------see this (outside of aside )   
       </article>
```

Below is a screenshot after making these changes.

[image]

Comment: the learned is far apart from popularity, should i just use position relative to not mess the layout?

Comment: No.. I dont think its going to work..because its not an issue with positioning.

Answer (score -1):

Your can do this by css using css property :margin: 0 auto; and set a width to artical.

I have create a snippet for you to understand

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
article{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <article>
    This is an article
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP has clearly stated in his post that **neither <center> nor margin: auto; are working**.

Comment: @Lal you can see in my code the margin: auto is working kindly check the code before woting

Comment: We all know that `margin:0 auto` works very well. But the reason why the OP asked a new question in SO is only because the `margin:0` is not working for him. And he expects us to suggest a new solution and explain him why `margin 0 auto` is not working for him.

Comment: And the reason why `margin:0 auto` was not working for him is explained in my answer. Oh, a bit correction.. actually `margin:0 auto` was working well for him. Only thing was that it was inside an `<aside>` which didnt have sufficient width to make it centered.